# Can I read an HID iClass card with an android device?

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to read an HID iClass cards using the methods described in the [Advanced NFC API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html)?

Comment: Is there any update on this topic? I have some HID iClass tags and would like to read the "tag number" using Android. I have a USB reader which does output the "tag number" (keyboard wedge). However, on Android the tag remains undetected (no output what so ever). Any clues on where to start research?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to communicate to the card if it supports NFC-V (ISO-15693) technology.

**Update:** iClass cards use a different protocol from ISO-15693. So, I believe android device does not support iClass, as of this post.

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation that supports your updated answer?

Comment: Check this link.
http://events.ccc.de/congress/2010/Fahrplan/attachments/1784_HID-iClass-27C3.pdf